# Assert() - what is it good for ?

Tags: c++, assert

I don't understand the purpose of `assert()` .

My lecturer says that the purpose of assert is to find bugs .

For example :

```
double divide(int a , int b ) 
{
  assert (0 != b);
  return a/b;
}
```

Does the above assert justified ? I think that the answer is yes , because if my program 
doesn't supposed to work with `0` (the number zero) , but somehow a zero does find its way into the `b` variable , then something is wrong with the code .

Am I correct ?

Can you show me some examples for a **justified** assert() ?

Regards

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`assert` is used to validate things that should always be true if the
program is correct.  Whether `assert` is justified in your example
depends on the specification of `divide`: if `b != 0` is a precondition,
then the `assert` is usually the preferred way of verifying it: if
someone calls the function without fulfilling the preconditions, it is a
programming error, and you should terminate the program with extreme
prejudice, doing as little additional work as possible.  (Usually.
There are applications where this is not the case, and where it is
better to throw an exception, and stumble along, hoping for the best.)
If, however, the specification of `divide` defines somw behavior when `b
== 0` (e.g. return +/-Inf), then you should implement this instead of
using assert.

Also, it's possible to turn the `assert` off, if it turns out that it
takes too much runtime.  Generally, however, this should only be done in
critical sections of code, and only if the profiler shows that you
really need it.

FWIW: not related to your question, but the code you've posted will
return `0.0` for `divide( 1, 3 )`.  Somehow, I don't think that this is
what you wanted.

Answer (score 8):

Another aspect of assertions:
They are also a kind of documentation.

Instead of comments like

```
// ptr is never NULL
// vec has now n elements
```

better write

```
assert(ptr!=0);
assert(vec.size()==n);
```

Comments may become outdated over time and will cause confusion.
But assertions are verified all the time.
Comments can be ignored. Assertions cannot.

Answer (score 6):

You're pretty much spot-on in your assesment of `assert`, except for the fact you typically use `assert` during a debug-phase ... This is because you don't want an `assert` to trigger during production code ... throwing exceptions (and properly handling them) is the proper method for run-time error-management in production level code.

In general though, `assert` is used for *testing an assumption*.  If an assumed condition is not met in the code during the debugging phase, especially when you are getting values that are out-of-bound for the desired input, you want your program to bail out at the point that the error is encountered so you can fix it.  For instance, suppose you were calling a function that returned a pointer, and that function should *never* return a `NULL` pointer value.  In other words returning a `NULL` value is not just some indicator of an error-condition, but it means that the *assumption* of how you imagine your code works is wrong.  That is a good place to use `assert` ... you assume your program will work one way, and if it doesn't then you don't want that error propagating to cause some crazy hard-to-find bug somewhere else ... you want to nix it right when it occurs.

Finally, you can combine built in macros with `assert` such as `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` that will give you the file and line number in the code where the assert took place to help you quickly identify the problem area.

Comment: You've got it backwards.  `assert` is active by default; you have to define the preprocessor symbol `NDEBUG` to turn it off.  (Something you should only do if the profiler says you must.)

Comment: And throwing exceptions is only the proper way of responding if someone is going to catch them, and do something reasonable with them.  Even in production code, you want an assertion failure in case of error---if nothing else, the client can send you the core dump, so you can do a post mortum.

Comment: And third: it's not "your" assert, and you can't place anything in it.  It's part of the standard library, and you aren't allowed to redefine it (at least if you include any standard headers).

Comment: @JamesKanze Okay, thanks for the tips, although I will have to disagree on your second point about exceptions and assertions ... I've found that customers will simply switch to another application from a competitor if the program is "crashy" because of assertions.  At least by handling exceptions you can avoid the program simply bailing on you.  Most customers I've worked with have no idea how to fetch a core dump, etc. ... They just stop using the app...

Comment: If that's the way your customers are, then replacing `assert` with something else in the delivered code is a requirement.  (I'll admit that my clients have always been people running large systems, who know that complex programs sometime fail.  And understand the importance of providing us with all of the information possible.)

Comment: What are you referring to in your final paragraph? How can one use macros like `__FILE__` and `__NAME__` together with `assert`?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of an assert is to signal out unexpected behavior during debugging (as it's only available in a debug build). Your example is a justified case of assert. The next line would probably crash, **but** with the assert there you have the option to break execution right before the line is hit, and do some debugging.

This is usually done in parallel with exceptions - you assert to signal that something is wrong, and throw an exception to treat the case gracefully (even exiting the program):

```
double divide(int a , int b ) 
{
  assert (0 != b);
  if ( b )
     return a/b;
  throw division_by_0_exception();
}
```

There are cases where you want to continue execution, but still want to signal that something went wrong.

Comment: `assert` is available unless you explicitly disable it.  Normally, it should be active in the code you deliver.  (And _all_ builds are "debug builds", since in practice, you're going to have to debug them.)

Answer (score 1):

Assert is used to test assumptions about your code in a debug environment. Asserts generally have no effect on your final build.

Whether or not it is a valid test is another matter entirely. We can't answer that without intimate knowledge of your application.

Asserts should never fail. If you see any possibility that the assertion could fail, then you need an if statement instead to handle those cases where the condition is not true. Assertions are only for conditions that you believe will never fail.

Comment: I'd replace "Assertions are only for conditions that you believe will never fail." with "Assertions are only for conditions that you believe should never fail."

Comment: Why? An assertion is an assumption that it will never fail. If it could fail, then you need a test, whether it *should* fail or not.

Comment: Asserts are for handling the cases where what you know isn't so.  You know an assert will never fail, but of course, they do.  (Otherwise, we wouldn't bother with them.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, in other words an assumption. That's how I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Asserts are used to check invariants during code execution, those are the conditions that are assumed by programmer to always stay the same, if they differ from assumptions then there is a bug in the code.

Asserts can be also used for checking preconditions and postconditions, the first is checked before some code block and verifies if provided data/state is correct, the second one checks whether the outcome of some calculations are correct. This helps to narrow where problems/bugs might be located:

```
assert( /*preconditions*/ );
/*here some algorithm - and maybe more asserts checking invariants*/
assert( /*postconditions*/ );
```

Some examples of justified asserts:

1. Checking function return value, for example if you call some external API function and you know that it returns some error value only in case of programming error:

WinAPI Thread32First function requires that provided LPTHREADENTRY32 structure has properly assigned dwSize field, in case of error it fails. This failure should be catched by assert.

1. If function accepts pointer to some data, then add assert at the start of function to verify that it is non-null. This makes sense if this function cannot work on null pointer.
2. If you have a lock on mutex with set timeout then if this timeout ends then you can use assert to indicate possible race condition / deadlock

... and many many more

Nice trick with asserts is to add some info inside, ex.:

assert(false && "Reason for this assert");

"Reason for this assert" will show up to you in a message box

You might also want to know that we also have static asserts that indicate errors during compilation.